# Which mineral is more efficient to gather during Gold Event?

Tags: king-of-avalon-dragon-warfare

During [Gold Event](http://king-of-avalon.wikia.com/wiki/Gold_Event) in King of Avalon (Dragon Warfare), you get the 1 point at gathering stage per each:

- 20 food,
- 20 wood,
- 4 iron,
- 1 silver.

[image: King of Avalon, Dragon Warfare, Gold Event, Event Center, gathering]

Assuming all skills and boosts for gathering all minerals are equal (no extra bonuses), which food or mineral is the most efficient to gather in terms of ratio between the default speed and received points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All things being equal, the rss are weighted to be exactly the same same. The best way to go is to set your dragon up for fastest resource collection and raise the dragon level of the resource that your alliance farm is set to. So if alliance farm is sawmill, set dragon for wood collection. Add 50% resource buff. Then split your army equally sending first march to alliance resource and other marches to other resources. Us all the marches you have and send back out as they come in. You will collect more than double speed from first march. And 1.5x from the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Resource quantity for different resource types for same tile level are exactly the same but a big difference can be your economy research + talent setup. And these days dragon effect on gathering speed is same across all resource types.

So depending on research, you might prefer to gather food or wood since usually these items are easier to complete in research and talent.